# How to get a "moving query" with firebase

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have data stored with `timestamps` as IDs. I need to only get new data when the data passes the `where` query clause. The data also has the same timestamp in a key named `day`.
The code is written in Golang but it only gets the data with a static timestamp from when the function is first called. How do I get the most recent data with a query that `moves`?

Query

```golang
snapshots := org.firestoreClient.Collection(
     fmt.Sprintf("metrics/%v/%v", "id", "data-collectioin"),
).Where("day", ">=", time.Now().UTC().Add(time.Duration(-7) * time.Hour * 24))
.Snapshots(context.Background())

// Listening loop does not terminate
for {
    snapshot, err := snapshots.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    var decodingErr error
    // Doc Iterating loop terminates at the last document
    for {
        store, vErr := snapshot.Documents.Next()
        if vErr != nil {
            break
        }
        // unmarshal data to result struct
        // ....
        // check for old data 
        if result.Day.UTC().Before(time.Now().UTC().Add(time.Duration(-7) * time.Hour * 24)) {
            log.Println("has old data")
            continue
        }
        // save to cache
        addToSlice()
    }
    saveToCache(slice)
}
```

I expect new data every 24 hours, after which the server running this query will get new data. and save the data to the cache

Maybe my understanding is wrong but 14 days after this query is run, the cache-store will have data from 14 days ago not just data from the last 7 days. I would like to only have data from the last 7 days. The `if (old-data) continue` skips old data but with a large dataset and given that I only need entries that pass the initial query (absolute), that will be a lot of skipping over data I don't need

```
Output
day 0:

day 1: 
  has old data
day 2:
  has old data
  has old data
day 3:
  has old data
  has old data
  has old data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have any dynamic parameters or something like that. If you want to request data for a new timestamp, you'll have to run a new query with the new timestamp.

Most applications thus run a periodic query to clean up expired data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use a function to archive the effect I wanted

```golang
query := func () firestore.Query {
    return org.firestoreClient.Collection(
        fmt.Sprintf("metrics/%v/%v", "id", "collection"),
    ).Where("day", ">=", time.Now().UTC().Add(time.Duration(-7) * time.Hour * 24))
}

// Listening loop does not terminate
for {
    snapshot, err := query().Snapshots(context.Background()).Next()
    // ...
    if cacheIsEmpty {
        // initial data
        // init cache
        addDataToCache(snapshot.Documents))
    } else {
        // clear cache
        // re-run query with new timestamp
        addDataToCache(query().Documents(context.Background()))
    }
}
```